# No foreign key exist in db created

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I have created many entities in jpa.
When i checked in the database, i don't see any foreign key.

```
@Entity
public class Lodger implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long lodgerId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "lodger")
    private List<AccountOperation> accountOperationList;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class AccountOperation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long accountOperationId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id")
    private Lodger lodger;
    ...
}
```

In this example i was thinking to get a foreign key in the account operation class.

table automaticaly created
http://www.wepaste.com/table_example/

Why?

Comment: have you enabled hibernate to create your tables?

Comment: in the application.properties, i have spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

Comment: I took your classes and ran them in my sample app that uses MySQL.  Foreign keys were correctly generated.  Hibernate generated the queries `create table account_operation (id bigint not null auto_increment, lodger_id bigint, primary key (id))`, `create table lodger (id bigint not null auto_increment, primary key (id))` and `alter table account_operation add constraint FK_hagdtay66ikbm9iwknr2shlsr foreign key (lodger_id) references lodger (id)`.  Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE account_operation` on your database and post the output?  A sample app would also be useful to investigate.

Comment: If you want to take a look at my sample, you can find it on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-boot-rest/tree/master/src/main/java/org/example/domain/lodging).

Comment: i checked you example, you use h2. what orm have you used, don't find any trace?

Comment: This is a standard Spring Boot application that uses Spring Data JPA with Hibernate as the JPA provider.  Spring Boot includes both H2 and MySQL.  Check the Spring Boot documentation and set the database details in [application.properties](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-boot-rest/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties) for MySQL.  That is the only change to be made to execute the application against MySQL.  Then, running `mvn clean test` will run all the tests, generating the database schema on the MySQL server.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate does not automatically generate foregein keys when generating dlls. I would recommend to turn of the generate-dll option as it may create inconsistent databases as the complexity increases. also check out either spring boot default database administration options:

- [Flyway](http://www.liquibase.org/)
- [Liquibase](http://flywaydb.org/)

The main difference between the two relies in the fact that while both may be administrared with SQL, Liquibase offers a more database agnostic formats such as XML, and YML for the creation of your database

Comment: Can you point to the source from where you obtained the information that Hibernate does not generate foreign keys?

Comment: with: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create i get foreign key.